# How can I verify the Dictionary values I've assigned to a combobox are what I think they are?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, combobox, valuemember

I've got this code to assign a Dictionary to a combobox:

```
Dictionary<String, String> dict = ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetReportGeneratorsDictionary();
comboBoxReportRunners.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
comboBoxReportRunners.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxReportRunners.ValueMember = "Value";
```

I want to verify that the items' DisplayMembers and ValueMembers are what I hope they are. This seems like a logical way to test that:

```
foreach (var v in comboBoxReportRunners.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(v.DisplayMember.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(v.ValueMember.ToString());
}
```

...but it doesn't compile; I get, "*'object' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMember' and no extension method 'DisplayMember' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'*" and the same err msg for 'ValueMember'

What do I need to see (one time only) what values are stored as each Items' DisplayMember and ValueMember?

Comment: What is the run-time type of the objects referred to by the variable `v`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> v in comboBoxReportRunners.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(v.Key.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(v.Value.ToString());
}
```

Dictionary stores data using KeyValuePair

Answer (score 2):

`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are properties of the combo box and not of the items contained in it. As the error says, the items in the combo box are of type `Object`, so if you want to access their properties you have to to a cast first. You data source is of type `Dictionary<String, String>` which is a collection of `KeyValuePair<string,string>`, so in the `foreach` loop you have to use this type (there are two possible ways):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> v in comboBoxReportRunners.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(v.Key.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(v.Value.ToString());
}
```

or

```
foreach (var v in comboBoxReportRunners.Items)
{
    KeyValuePair<string,string> val = v as KeyValuePair<string,string>;
    MessageBox.Show(val.Key.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(val.Value.ToString());
}
```